# GeoTiff import appears to be flat in BlenderGIS

Tags: dem, geotiff-tiff, blendergis

I an very new to GIS and I am trying to import a GeoTiff file into Blender to view it as a model before importing into unity. For some reason when I import the file into blender as a raw DEM it appears to be flat.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have [BlenderGIS](https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS) installed in your blender software, you can import `georeferenced raster` like GeoTiff images from `Import → Georeferenced raster`:

[image]

Then select your raster file, and under Import georaster → Select `As DEM`, check `Fill nodata values`

[image]

the output should be something like this:

[image]

Go to `Object Modifier` → under `View` increase the value to 10 and the render of the DEM will be enhanced:

[image]

You can refer to this article for detailed information [Shaded relief with BlenderGIS, part 1](https://wanderingcartographer.wordpress.com/2014/11/14/shaded-relief-with-blendergis-part-1/)